# Выполнять функцию getKey() только при первом вызове action

Tags: php, yii

Проблема в следующем: в контроллере создаю переменную $key.
там же создаю функцию getKey(), в которой генерирую случайную строку с помошью unique().
а в экшине уже получаю значение этой функции. Но проблема в том что action вызывается многократно через ajax и при каждом вызове экшина в $key заносится новое значение, хотя в getKey() я проверяю равно ли оно null или нет. Так как заставить getKey() работать только при вервом вызове экшина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как на счет занести в сессию и брать ее оттуда? Через setState, Yii::app()->session или напрямую в $_SESSION. Если она так часто нужна, то можно подумать о кэшировании.

Можно так:

```
Yii::app()->session->add("key", $key); //положить
...
$key = Yii::app()->session->get("key"); //получить
```

Вот докуметация: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: @LANSELOT, обновил ответ.

Comment: Получаю: "Class name must be a valid object or a string in..." А если я кладу в сессию в одном экшине, а получаю в другом это сути не меняет?

Comment: @LANSELOT, они предназначены хранить данные в течении небольшого времени между переходами по страницам.  
Приведи полную строку ошибки

Comment: Class name must be a valid object or a string in W:\domains\localhost\protected\controllers\PostsController.php on line 182

это стока: $this->key = $Yii::app()->session->get("$this->key");

Comment: @LANSELOT, а зачем в get передавать $this->key? В этом ошибка.  
Ты записываешь пару ключ=>значение. Потом в get передаешь ключ и получаешь значение. Нужно get("key")